# how to change the themes and icons of Android 2.2 OS?

Tags: android

I am Optimizing the Android 2.2 OS to make it in such a way that it can be ported to the  tablet. Can anyone suggest me how to change the themes and icons of Android 2.2 OS.

Comment: You shouldn't have greetings in your question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/138411

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a similar question in another forum about a custom UI, and why Sense from HTC is the way it is.  I was given a brief answer, but I think it applies to you too: It involves a custom UI application that overlays on top of what is pre-existing.

Comment: Shawn Strickland, I am not getting your answer.Plz tell me the details

Comment: From what I can tell, what you need is an overlay application that replaces the UI features you're looking to augment or redo in some way.  There is a sample application from the developer community on http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html that you might find useful.